# Apache mod_ssl to use OpenSSL ENGINE on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, apache2, openssl, mod-ssl

I have installed OpenSSL 1.0.1f and created an Engine for RSA acceleration using GPU. The Engine is dynamic so it is known globally.
Then I have installed Apache `$ sudo apt-get install apache2`, created self signed certificates in order to provide HTTPS services, modified the configuration files, etc.
These two parts work properly but separately, i.e. when I try to specify Apache to use the RSA engine (in OpenSSL 1.0.1f) it just fails with message:

```
* The apache2 configtest failed. Not doing anything.
Output of config test was:
AH00526: Syntax error on line 3 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default-ssl.conf:
SSLCryptoDevice: Invalid argument; must be one of: 'builtin' (none), 'rsax' (RSAX engine support), 'dynamic' (Dynamic engine loading support)
```

So my questions:
Under Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit, is Apache using other version of OpenSSL then the version installed by me?
And how can I link the Apache with the OpenSSL in order to use that Engine?

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   Jan 14 2016 17:45:23
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steps that finally worked for me:

1.Install OpenSSL from sources, specifying `-DOPENSSL_LOAD_CONF` when running `./config`
1.1.Create/build your OpenSSL engine and add it to your `openssl.cnf` file
2.Install httpd from sources, using these commands:

```
CFLAGS='-DSSL_EXPERIMENTAL_ENGINE -DSSL_ENGINE -DOPENSSL_LOAD_CONF' ./configure --enable-ssl --with-ssl=/usr/local/ssl --with-pcre=/usr/local/pcre --enable-so      
make       
make install
```

2.1.Edit `httpd-ssl.conf` by adding `SSLCryptoDevice engine_id` and make sure that when execute `$ openssl engine`, the `engine_id` specifier appears on the list. Also, you have to create self-signed cerificate and private key, modify the `httpd.conf` file, but this is not the subject of this question. Search: how to configure HTTPS on Apache.
3.`$ httpd -k restart` and that is all.

Comment: can you be a little more specific about `how to add Custom OpenSSL engine to the openssl.conf file?` After installing `openSSL` from the source, I am looking at the `openssl/ssl/openssl.cnf`.  I'm not seeing anything mentioned about the default engine here(I guess I need to replace the default engine with my custom engine).

Comment: you need to specify `engine_id = your_custom_engine`